# knowing the type before test in erlang

Tags: erlang

I have this code :

```
                    io:format("id retour: ~w\n",[Idretour]),
```

I want to know the type of **Idretour**

because I want to add  this test : `if Idretour =:= 40 ->`

may be this line can help us to know the type of **Idretour**

```
io:format("id retour: ~w\n",[Idretour]),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the test `if Idretour =:= 40` no matter the type of `Idretour`.

What I think you are looking for is:

```
case Idretour of
    Int when is_integer(Idretour) -> do_domething_with_int;
    _ -> not_an_int
end
```